# The way of converting a string to a variable in a loop?

Tags: variable-definitions, procedural-programming

I have 60 txt files which I want to import them into Mathematica using a `Do` loop. Each file contains some numbers (more precisely, a list of numbers). I want to put the content of each file in a variable with a name that is the same as the original file. Now, the problem is, I have no idea how to build a variable automatically with the same name in each loop run.

To make things clear, I wrote the following sample code

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
(* reading all files in the directory *)
all = FileNames[]
Do[
 name = StringSplit[all[[i]], "_"][[1]];
 NUMkinPmat = ToExpression[Import[all[[i]], "Lines"]];
 , {i, Length[all]}]
```

Where `all[[1]]` is `NUMkinPmat_1836.txt` for example, namely the name of the first file. I want to build a variable called `NUMkinPmat`. The `name` gets what I'm looking for (`NUMkinPmat`), however, I don't know how to put `all[[i]]` in it, so wrote it manually in the above code. I can't write in this way also:

```
ToExpression[StringSplit[all[[1]], "-"][[1]]] = 
  ToExpression[Import["VARkinPmat_1836.txt", "Lines"]];
```

because it returns `Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[NUMdenE_1836.txt] is Protected.` error.
I hope I got my point across. Any idea?

Comment: In general I don't think it's a good idea to encode information in the variable name. Better to use something like `data["NUMkinPmat_1836.txt"] = Import["NUMkinPmat_1836.txt", "Lines"]` etc. In this way you can look up the data by referencing the file name as a pseudo-argument to the `data` symbol.

Comment: As stated by @Roman, this is generally a bad idea. If you _really_ insist, take a look at [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html). You can do something like: ``Evaluate@Symbol[name] = NUMkinPmat ``

Comment: @Roman Thanks, but when I try your code by `ToExpression` I get error.

Comment: @Domen I don't insist in my idea, but give me a better method to recall 60 imported files in the next calculations. Sorry I didn't got your mean about symbol, can explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example *data* is cleared in advance for reruns.  `Clear[name]` clears *name* not *data* so `Apply` is used.

```
filename = "data.txt";
name = First[StringSplit[filename, "."]];
Apply[Clear, List[name]]
With[{x = ToExpression[name]}, x = Import[filename, "Lines"]]

data
```

> 1,2,3

You can also use `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression`.

```
all = FileNames[]
Do[
 name = StringSplit[all[[i]], "_"][[1]];
 Apply[Clear, List[name]];
 With[{x = Symbol[name]}, x = Import[all[[i]], "Lines"]],
 {i, Length[all]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I replaced `name = all[[i]]; vname = StringSplit[name, "_"][[1]];` by yours and put it in the loop, and it worked! It just needs an additional `ToExpression` command when I when plot using data. Can explain more about the line started by `With`?

Comment: Usefully in this case [With](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) has the attribute *HoldAll* which enable the variable name to be handled. See the details section.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two aspects of your code: (1) don't encode information in variable names, as commented above, and (2) don't read everything in a `Do` loop but rather lazy-read on demand. Concretely, using a memoizing field `data`:

```
data[name_String] := data[name] = Import[name, "Lines"]
```

In this way, every time you ask for a specific `data`, the content is memoized (buffered) in the kernel. For example,

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
all = FileNames[]

data[all[[1]]]
(*    the data as read    *)
```

reads the file only when called for the first time; at later times the cached (memoized) data are used. So everything can be read lazily (on-demand) without pre-reading everything in a `Do` loop.

Comment: How to implement this method with `ToExpression` because I need to this commend to convert my data to correct ones.